# Java HashMap add new entry while iterating

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

In a HashMap

```
map = new HashMap<String,String>();

it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    entry = it.next();
    it.remove(); //safely remove a entry
    entry.setValue("new value"); //safely update current value
    //how to put new entry set inside this map
    //map.put(s1,s2); it throws a concurrent access exception

}
```

When i trying to add a new entry to map it throws `ConcurrentModificationException`. For remove and update iterator has safely removing methods. How to add new entry while iterating?

Comment: Create a new `Map<String, String> foo` instance and set the desired values there. At the end of your process, assign this map to your old map by using `map = foo;`.

Comment: i thought it. there is no other direct ways right?

Comment: You could do it by using `ConcurrentHashMap` but that seems overkill. Also, these clean-up tasks are not good to do using an iterator.

Answer (score 14):

You need to consider what it means to put a value to a Map whilst iterating. HashMap defines no order over which its entries will be iterated over. So when you put a new entry, should the entry be returned by the iterator later or not. Consistency of behaviour is important. However, whichever way you decide you'll get inconsistent behaviour when you put a new value to a preexisting key. If the key has already been iterated over then the change won't appear and will appear if the key has yet to be produced by the iterator.

A simple way to overcome this problem is to create a temporary Map of the new key-value pairs and add the temporary Map to the main Map at the end of your iteration.

```
Map<String,String> values = ...

Map<String,String> temp = new HashMap<>();
for (Entry<String,String> entry : values.entrySet()) {
    if ("some value".equals(entry.getValue()) {
        temp.put(entry.getValue(), "another value");
    }
}
values.putAll(temp);
```

Comment: Consistent behavior is not always needed, especially with probabilistic algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `ConcurrentHashMap` to add elements while iterating the collection. HashMap uses fail-fast iterator, which throws ConcurrentModificationException when the collection is updated while iterating. Whereas `ConcurrentHashMap` uses fail-safe iterator, which basically works on the clone of the underlying collection and hence allows modification while iterating.

Comment: I think using `ConcurrentHashMap` in this case may be overkill.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
map = new HashMap<String,String>();

it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    entry = it.next();
    entry.setValue("new value"); // update current value
}
```

I checked the HashMap implementation, it does not change its modification count when updating an entry like this.  I also see no reason why this shouldn't be allowed.  Nothing is removed, nothing is added and no keys are changed.

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to create an array with the current elements and then iterate through the array:

```
Feature[] initialFeatures = featureMap.values().toArray(new Feature[featureMap.values().size()]);

for (Feature feature : initialFeatures)
{/* Code that can safely add to the featureMap */}
```